# What is the easiest way to remove a word from a string in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Hi I have a excel in which one sheet A contains a table with a column which has  comma separated value and another sheet B having some data.
So what I need I need to search the data from B to the sheet A comma separated column and if it is found remove that data from the string. Here I need to work on these columns based on another column. For Example:

Sheet A

### column a | comma separated column

a     |          1,2,3,4

b     |          1,3,5,7

c     |          1,2,3,4

d     |          1,3,5,7

e     |          1,2,3,4

Sheet B

### column a | column b

a   |           1

a   |           2

b   |           1

b    |          3

c    |          1

c    |          4

d     |         3

d     |         7

Result:

### column a | comma separated column

a   |   3,4

b   |   5,7

c   |   2,3

d   |   1,5

e   |   1,2,3,4

Is it possible to fetch the result? I am new in excel and macro but tried may ways still finding the exact solution. Is there any easiest way whether using macro or excel formulas.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a site for just demanding code from other users, it's about helping with each other's problems.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Efficiency may be an issue with larger data sets.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim shtAList As Range, rngA As Range
    Dim shtBList As Range, rngB As Range

    Set shtAList = Worksheets("A").Range("A1:A5")
    Set shtBList = Worksheets("B").Range("A1:A8")

    For Each rngA In shtAList
        For Each rngB In shtBList
            If rngB = rngA Then
                rngA.Offset(0, 1) = StripString(rngA.Offset(0, 1), rngB.Offset(0, 1))
            End If
        Next rngB
    Next rngA
End Sub

Function StripString(csv As Range, strip_string As String) As String
    Dim strings() As String, i As Integer, temp As String, result As String

    temp = vbNullString
    strings = VBA.Split(csv, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(strings)
        If strings(i) <> strip_string Then
            temp = temp & strings(i) & ","
        End If
    Next i

    result = IIf(VBA.Right$(temp, 1) = ",", VBA.Left$(temp, Len(temp) - 1), temp)
    StripString = result
End Function
```

- `Main` is simply looping over your two lists to find matches.
- `StripString` is where the comparison of strings and stripping takes place